# How do I locate phones who have my app installed from inside the App? iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, location

I want to have my App find a locate "nearby" people.

Sort of like how **Venmo** allows you to see nearby people and make payments them. I don't even know where to begin. My first though would be **bluetooth** but I feel that the process is sluggish and I doubt **Venmo** was utilizing bluetooth because I hadn't turned it on. Location seems to be my second instinct but that seems inefficient.

Any tips or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, You want to locate nearby phones that download your app. 
 1. You will have to ask user with a popUp to turn on its location services, if its not already. For getting location of the  user you will need to import CoreLocation framework into your project. 
 There are many sources and links online for using apple location services (note not map framework). [Apple Ref Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html)

2.You will have to post that location cordinate/position data via Json/ Xml with preferably [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i) to your backend webserver. (can be in php) There are many online services which offer backend support Google, parse,etc

3.By using [APNS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)
your iOS device will be notified after that event. Now if you want only nearby users to be notified, you should calculate the distance between 2 devices , again using location services.`CLLocationDistance distanceInMeters = [locationA distanceFromLocation:locationB];` 
 If you plan to make only 1 such application, you will have to sort out the architecture for users and owner. Hope this helps.  [Link1](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/)